# Inserting Point into PostGIS geometry column from golang?

Tags: postgis, go-golang

I have this go code to insert data in to postgresql:

```
sqlStatement := `
    INSERT INTO my_table (
        column_name, geog)
    VALUES ($1, ST_GeomFromText('Point($2 $3)'))
`
```

and then

```
_, err = db.Exec(sqlStatement,
        'whatever',
        longitude,
        latitude)
```

where `latitude` and `longitude` are `float64`.

I get the following error:

```
pq: got 3 parameters but the statement requires 1
```

I also tried the following, using the [go-postgis](https://github.com/cridenour/go-postgis) library:

```
sqlStatement := `
        INSERT INTO my_table (
            column_name, geog)
        VALUES ($1, ST_GeomFromText($2))
    `
_, err = db.Exec(sqlStatement,
            'whatever',
            postgis.PointS{4326,longitude, latitude}
)
```

In this case, the error message is

```
pq: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
```

Any hints on what is the correct way to do this simple operation?

Comment: Does `db.Exec` expand variables in single quoted strings?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know this Go library at all but just looking the main page (your link), it seems (in there example) that the return of postgis.PointS should be in EWKB, not WKT, so you should try ST_GeomFromEWKB instead of ST_GeomFromText in your second example

Answer (score 1):

My working solution is below. Use a function to create the string required as input to `ST_GeomFromText` and then in the `exec` statement, call that function as single argument

```go
func LatLngToString(lat float64, lng float64) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Point(%f %f)", lat, lng)
}
        
createStmnt := `
        INSERT INTO upstream_packet (name, location)
        VALUES ($1,ST_GeomFromText($2))`

        _, err := conn.Exec(
            context.Background(),
            createStmnt,
            name,
            LatLngToString(Latitude, Longitude),
        )
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I made geometry type fields autogenerated. That is, geometry (or your geometry type column name) is automatically generated when you insert longitude and latitide. Here is the example:

```
--  function that creates GEOMETRY point from given inputs
create or replace 
function create_geometry_point (long DOUBLE PRECISION, lat DOUBLE PRECISION)
  returns GEOMETRY
  language sql 
  immutable 
as $$
  select ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', long::text, ' ', lat::text, ')'))
$$;


CREATE TABLE driver_orders (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  address VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  longitude DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
  latitude DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
  -- add autogenerated 'location' column
  location GEOMETRY
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS
    (create_geometry_point(longitude, latitude))
      stored
);
```

Then you can insert data providing longitude and latitude.

```
var (
    query = `
    INSERT INTO driver_orders (
        address,
        time,
        longitude,
        latitude
    ) values (
        $1,
        $2,
        $3,
        $4
    ) RETURNING id;`
    id                       int64
    order                    ors.Order
)

row := or.db.QueryRow(query,
    req.Address,
    req.Time[0:19],
    req.Longitude,
    req.Latitude
)
```